# How can I show a list of installed apps ("Metro" only) in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, modern-ui, windows-store

I want to see a list of all of the apps installed in Windows 10. I don't mean traditional desktop programs - just the "Metro" apps, including the system ones.

I can see everything mixed together (desktop and Metro) in the "Apps & features" section of the System Settings, but I can't tell which are the Metro apps.

I can see only the third party things by clicking my face and picking "My Library" in the Windows Store. But the default apps, like "Money" and "News", aren't there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get a [Windows PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) prompt, which you can do on Windows 10 by clicking on the [Start button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start_menu#Start_button), or hitting Ctrl-Esc, then typing `PowerShell` then right-click on `Windows PowerShell` and choose "Run as administrator". Then type `Get-AppxPackage` and hit Enter. If you don't want to see all of the details for the installed packages, just the name, use `Get-AppxPackage | findstr "^Name"` - put the `^` before "Name" so that you get lines beginning with "Name" and not those beginning with "PackageFullName" and "PackageFamilyName". You should see a list of the ["Modern", aka "Metro" apps](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-remove-all-bundled-modern-apps-from-your-user-account-in-windows-8/).

Comment: That's great. Thanks! There's some pretty interesting stuff in there. Apparently the "Groove Music" app is still called Zune internally!