# How can I list all apps installed from Microsoft Store?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-store

How can I find which of my apps are installed from Microsoft Store (or present in Microsoft Store)?  I can search for an individual application by name in the Store app, and check for "This product is installed", but I don't see the way to list all installed apps, like there is in Google Play Store for example.

The answer for [How can I show a list of installed apps (“Metro” only) in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1029965/how-can-i-show-a-list-of-installed-apps-metro-only-in-windows-10) shows internal app name, which can be bit different from user visible name, especially if system language is not set to English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Microsoft Store, click on the three dots in the upper right corner, choose Downloads and Updates. In my case there are all my apps.

[image]

---

`UPDATE: 2022-12-02`

Now you need to click on the `library` icon on the left-hand side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or list all MS apps with PowerShell run as Admin with the right click and command:

To list all apps:

Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Select-Object Name

Comment: The author isn't looking for just Microsoft-published UWP applications. They are looking for ALL applications installed through the Microsoft Store.  Please take a minute to read the question, and [edit] your answer so that it answers the author's question.