# How to uninstall an app from Microsoft Store (e.g. Instagram)

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-store

I want to uninstall the Instagram metro app. How can I do this? In `appwiz.cpl` it is not listed. I know how to [display](https://superuser.com/questions/1029965/how-can-i-show-a-list-of-installed-apps-metro-only-in-windows-10) all metro apps but not how to uninstall.

Comment: **Deinstall**. Did you mean : `Uninstall` ?

Comment: I am too german for this platform *g*, of course: uninstall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you right-click the icon within the Start menu's All Apps list, it should present you with an option to **Uninstall** similar to the Twitter app on my laptop:

[image: Twitter]